# Entity Framework properties how does it work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here are four different approaches to defining an Entity class in Entity Framework.  Can someone tell me what is the difference in the way each approach works and also recommend which of these approaches to use?

```
// Approach 1
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

// Approach 2
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Address = new Address();
    }

}

// Approach 3
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

// Approach 4
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Address = new Address();
    }

}
```

Can I please ask for any good explanation of the differences?

Are the differences related to Lazy loading vs. Eager loading?

Which is better and why?

Comment: In my opinion Approach 3 is good.  You can find better explanation here http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/lazy-loading-eager-loading-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework-4

Comment: Read the documentation: [Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should look like:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }    
}
```

**Explanations:**

1. We need to mark our navigation properties as `virtual` to enable EF lazy loading at runtime. EF creates a user proxy object inheriting from your user class and marking Address as virtual allows EF to override this property and add lazy loading support code.
2. Having an AddressId as a FK for Address navigation property essentially converts your User-Address association to a "Foreign Key Association". These type of associations are preferred since they are easier to work with when it comes to updates and modifications.
3. Unless you have a navigation property in the form of collection of objects (e.g. `IList<Address>`) you don't need to initialize it in your constructor. EF will do that for you automatically if you include them in your queries.

Comment: 1. _If_ you want to use lazy loading. 2. False, EF works just fine without foreign key properties. 3. You don't _need_ to initialize collection type navigation properties.

Comment: No. 1: You always MAY WANT to use lazy loading. The object should allow that - the using program then may turn that off and use eager loading.

Comment: 1. Agree. You want that because you can still opt out by eager fetching your association.

Comment: 2. FK associations have been introduced by EF team to deal with all the issues that people have with associations in EF 3.5 where FK were hidden. Even the EF team recommends to choose FK associations whenever possible.

Comment: 3. Sure you can keep them uninitialized but then you will find yourself initializing them all over you code base which means unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks for your comment though :)

Comment: Sure, you can defend it like that. I interpreted it as "you _must_", just wanted to clear that up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was just trying to give some advice on "best practices" when it comes to EF and navigation properties. Of course it will still work without having those 3 points. Thanks :)